# Detecting environment with Meteor.js?

Tags: environment-variables, meteor

Anybody figure out syntax or a pattern yet for detecting hosting environment using Meteor.js?  I've got Heroku buildpacks working, and have a dev/production environment, but I'm kind of drawing a blank on how to have my app detect which environment it's running in.

Is there a way to have node.js detect which port it's running on?  I was hoping there might be something low-level like app.address().port, but that doesn't seem to work...

Edit:  This is the solution that worked for me.  Note that the following needs to be run on the server, so it needs to be included in server\server.js, or a similar file.

```js
if (Meteor.is_server) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        // we want to be able to inspect the root_url, so we know which environment we're in
        console.log(JSON.stringify(process.env.ROOT_URL));

        // in case we want to inspect other process environment variables
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(process.env));
    });
}
```

Also created the following:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  getEnvironment: function(){
    if(process.env.ROOT_URL == "http://localhost:3000"){
        return "development";
    }else{
        return "staging";
    }
  }
 });
```

Which allows for the following on client side:

```js
 Meteor.call("getEnvironment", function (result) {
      console.log("Your application is running in the " + result + "environment.");
 });
```

Thanks Rahul!

Comment: If you want to post the code that worked, just edit your own question and mention that it worked for you, or post an answer with the code. Editing my answer isn't really the right place to do it. :)

Comment: Oops!  Sorted things out.  Thanks again for the help!  :)

Comment: This code is extremely helpful, but as a FYI it initially returned undefined (I believe because of the async lag)

When I added error as the first argument and included it in a conditional to log the error, it worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can inspect the `process.env` variable on the server to find information about the current environment, including the port:

```
{ TERM_PROGRAM: 'Apple_Terminal',
  TERM: 'xterm-256color',
  SHELL: '/bin/bash',
  TMPDIR: '/var/folders/y_/212wz0cx5vs20yd7y2psnh7m0000gp/T/',
  Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render: '/tmp/launch-hch25f/Render',
  TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: '309',
  OLDPWD: '/usr/local/meteor/bin',
  TERM_SESSION_ID: '3FE307A0-B8FC-41AD-B1EB-FCFA0B8B25D1',
  USER: 'Rahul',
  COMMAND_MODE: 'unix2003',
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK: '/tmp/launch-gFCBXS/Listeners',
  __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING: '0x1F6:0:0',
  Apple_Ubiquity_Message: '/tmp/launch-QAWKHL/Apple_Ubiquity_Message',
  PATH: '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin',
  PWD: '/Users/Rahul/Documents/Sites/test',
  NODE_PATH: '/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules',
  SHLVL: '1',
  HOME: '/Users/Rahul',
  LOGNAME: 'Rahul',
  LC_CTYPE: 'UTF-8',
  SECURITYSESSIONID: '186a4',
  PORT: '3001',
  MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:3002/meteor',
  ROOT_URL: 'http://localhost:3000' }
```

Comment: Ah ha!  I think this might do the trick.  Just the right kind of clue to get me back on track!

Answer (score 3):

there is a direct Meteor function:

```
Meteor.isDevelopment
```

see: https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-isDevelopment

and for production:

```
Meteor.isProduction
```

both return a boolean

Answer (score 2):

I used a variation of the above with the `NODE_ENV` variable. See here for more info:

http://meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables#Checking%20the%20value%20of%20an%20Environment%20Variable

```
if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.methods
    'getEnvironment': -> process.env.NODE_ENV

Meteor.call 'getEnvironment', (err, result) ->
  if result == 'development'
    console.log('In dev env')
```