# How do I access process.env in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have tried:

```
alert(process.env.MONGO_URL);
```

everywhere is my Meteor project and always get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Do I need to include something? Meteor is written in javascript and all the same APIs are available so why isn't process defined?

Comment: Duplicate of [Detecting environment with Meteor.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184643/detecting-environment-with-meteor-js)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  console.log(process.env);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You must get the environment from the server side.  Try the following.

```
//In the client side
if (Meteor.isClient) {

   Meteor.call('getMongoUrlEnv', function(err, results) {
     alert("Mongo_URL=",results);
   });

}


if (Meteor.isServer) {

   Meteor.methods({
      getMongoUrlEnv: function(){
           var mongoURL = process.env.MONGO_URL;
           return mongoURL;
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can request for server side environment with this function.

```
//In the client side
if (Meteor.isClient) {

   Meteor.call('getEnv', "VARIABLE_NAME", function(err, results) {
     alert(results);
   });

}


if (Meteor.isServer) {

   Meteor.methods({
      getEnv: function(node){

           return process.env[node];;
      }
   });
}
```